# EPA: epa-file doesn't find recipients when saving encrypted journal, but is listed with M-x epa-file-select-keys

Tags: doom, gpg, epa, org-journal

I'm using doom, working with an encrypted org-journal and keys configured from a yubikey.  Opening/decrypting the journal works fine but after entering a new entry and trying to save, epa-file is defaulting to symmetric encryption and asks for a passphrase.

I set "epa-file-select-keys t" to enable the prompt for a key and no recipients are listed when trying to save the journal.  What's weird is if i run "M-x epa-file-select-keys" in the same buffer i DO see my key i want to use listed with the email address set in "epa-file-encrypt-to", and once selected there saving works using the key as expected.

Any idea what might be happening here, or how I might go about troubleshooting?
epa-file config in config.el:

```
(use-package! epa-file
  :config
  (setq epa-file-encrypt-to '("ratorres255@outlook.com"))
  :custom
  (epa-file-select-keys t))
```

Full config.el for doom:

```
;;; $DOOMDIR/config.el -*- lexical-binding: t; -*-

;; Place your private configuration here! Remember, you do not need to run 'doom
;; sync' after modifying this file!
;; Whenever you reconfigure a package, make sure to wrap your config in an
;; `after!' block, otherwise Doom's defaults may override your settings. E.g.
;;
;;   (after! PACKAGE
;;     (setq x y))
;;
;; The exceptions to this rule:
;;
;;   - Setting file/directory variables (like `org-directory')
;;   - Setting variables which explicitly tell you to set them before their
;;     package is loaded (see 'C-h v VARIABLE' to look up their documentation).
;;   - Setting doom variables (which start with 'doom-' or '+').
;;
;; Here are some additional functions/macros that will help you configure Doom.
;;
;; - `load!' for loading external *.el files relative to this one
;; - `use-package!' for configuring packages
;; - `after!' for running code after a package has loaded
;; - `add-load-path!' for adding directories to the `load-path', relative to
;;   this file. Emacs searches the `load-path' when you load packages with
;;   `require' or `use-package'.
;; - `map!' for binding new keys
;;
;;;; launch maximized
(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(left . 0))
(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(fullscreen . maximized))
;;
;;;; variables
(setq user-full-name "Randall Torres"
      user-mail-address "ratorres255@outlook.com")
(setq lucky/local-root
      (if (string-equal system-type "windows-nt")
          "C:/Users/rator"
        "~/"))
(setq lucky/sync-dir (expand-file-name "onedrive" lucky/local-root))
(setq lucky/org-dir (expand-file-name "org" lucky/sync-dir))
;;
;;;; aesthetics
(setq lucky/font-mono
      (if (string-equal system-type "windows-nt")
          "ShureTechMono NF"
        "ShureTechMono Nerd Font"))
(setq doom-font (font-spec :family lucky/font-mono :size 14)
      doom-big-font (font-spec :family lucky/font-mono :size 18)
      doom-theme 'doom-oksolar-dark)
(setq display-line-numbers-type t)
;;;; org-mode things
(after! org
  (setq
   org-directory lucky/org-dir
   org-id-locations-file (expand-file-name ".orgids" lucky/org-dir)
   org-id-locations-file-relative t
   org-roam-directory (expand-file-name "roam" lucky/org-dir)
   org-agenda-files (directory-files-recursively lucky/org-dir "\\.org$" t)
   org-todo-keywords `((sequence
                      "LATER(l)" "NOW(n)" "MAYBE(m)" "PROJECT(p)"
                      "|"
                      "DONE(d)" "NOPE(-)"))
   org-fold-catch-invisible-edits 'smart
   org-log-done 'time
   org-log-into-drawer t
   org-log-redeadline 'time
   org-log-reschedule 'time
   org-refile-use-outline-path 'file
   org-use-property-inheritance t
   org-roam-completion-everywhere t))
(use-package! org-journal
  :after org
  :custom
  (org-journal-dir (concat (file-name-as-directory org-directory) "journal"))
  (org-journal-file-format "%Y/%m/%Y%m%d")
  (org-journal-date-format "%A, %Y-%m-%d")
  (org-journal-encrypt-journal t)
  (org-journal-enable-encryption nil)
  (org-journal-enable-agenda-integration t))
(use-package! ox-extra
  :after org
  :config
  (ox-extras-activate '(latex-header-blocks ignore-headlines)))
(use-package! ox-latex
  :after org
  :config
  (setq org-latex-pdf-process
        '("pdflatex -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f"
        "bibtex %b"
        "pdflatex -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f"
        "pdflatex -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f"))
  (setq org-latex-hyperref-template nil)
  ;; (setq org-latex-prefer-user-labels t)
  ;; deleted unwanted file extensions after latexMK
  (setq org-latex-logfiles-extensions
        (quote ("lof" "lot" "tex~" "aux" "idx" "log" "out" "toc" "nav" "snm" "vrb" "dvi" "fdb_latexmk" "blg" "brf" "fls" "entoc" "ps" "spl" "bbl" "xmpi" "run.xml" "bcf" "acn" "acr" "alg" "glg" "gls" "ist")))

  (unless (boundp 'org-latex-classes)
    (setq org-latex-classes nil)))
(use-package! epa-file
  :config
  (setq epa-file-encrypt-to '("ratorres255@outlook.com"))
  :custom
  (epa-file-select-keys t))
;; in ~/.doom.d/+bindings.el
(map! :leader
      (:prefix ("j" . "journal") ;; org-journal bindings
        :desc "Create new journal entry" "j" #'org-journal-new-entry
        :desc "Open previous entry" "p" #'org-journal-previous-entry
        :desc "Open next entry" "n" #'org-journal-next-entry
        :desc "Search journal" "s" #'org-journal-search-forever))

;; The built-in calendar mode mappings for org-journal
;; conflict with evil bindings
(map!
 (:map calendar-mode-map
   :n "o" #'org-journal-display-entry
   :n "p" #'org-journal-previous-entry
   :n "n" #'org-journal-next-entry
   :n "O" #'org-journal-new-date-entry))

;; Local leader (<SPC m>) bindings for org-journal in calendar-mode
;; I was running out of bindings, and these are used less frequently
;; so it is convenient to have them under the local leader prefix
(map!
 :map (calendar-mode-map)
 :localleader
 "w" #'org-journal-search-calendar-week
 "m" #'org-journal-search-calendar-month
 "y" #'org-journal-search-calendar-year)
```

Answer (score 0):

Same behavior in Emacs 27.1 here. It looks like setting `epa-file-encrypt-to` globally does not work in some cases. For example, after decrypting a file while `epa-file-encrypt-to` is set globally, `epa-file-encrypt-to` gets locally set to an all-zero value:

```
epa-file-encrypt-to is a variable defined in ‘epa-hook.el’.
Its value is ("0000000000000000")
Local in buffer test.gpg; global value is 
("ueno@unixuser.org")
```

On the other hand, setting `epa-file-encrypt-to` as a file-local variable, as [recommended in the documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/epa/Encrypting_002fdecrypting-gpg-files.html#index-epa_002dfile_002dselect_002dkeys-1), works fine:

```
;; -*- epa-file-encrypt-to: ("ueno@unixuser.org") -*-
```